# Echo file_get_contents in a loop

Tags: php, loops, file-get-contents

I have some files in core directory. Example of file names: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
I want to echo them as (loop):

> content of file 1
>
> content of file 2
>
> content of file 3
>
> content of file 4
>
> content of file 5
>
> content of file 6
>
> ............
>
> ............

I tried the following code, but it is not working. **Please help!**

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
$x=file_get_contents('core/$i');
echo $x . '<br>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What are your files names?

Comment: Are they just 1,2,3,4,5,...

Comment: Yes they are just 1,2,3,4,5...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `$i` as type text by mentioning it in `''`

**Change your code to**

```
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=10; $i++)
{
$x=file_get_contents('core/'.$i);
echo $x . '<br>';
}
?>
```